# Display the results of foreach / eval / call expansion

Tags: debugging, foreach, makefile, eval

I'm trying to debug makefiles for a large project and I'm struggling `define TEMPLATE`/`endef` and `foreach`/`eval`/`call` constructs.  In particular I think I'm having a hard time figuring out which variables I need to reference with `$` and which I need to reference with `$$`.

I think would be easier for me to debug if I could see the actual results of the the `eval`/`call` expansion, before variable expansion.

For instance if we use the example in the [eval documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html#Eval-Function) for [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make), we have the following makefile-fragment:

```
 PROGRAMS    = server client

 server_OBJS = server.o server_priv.o server_access.o
 server_LIBS = priv protocol

 client_OBJS = client.o client_api.o client_mem.o
 client_LIBS = protocol
...
 define PROGRAM_template =
  $(1): $$($(1)_OBJS) $$($(1)_LIBS:%=-l%)
  ALL_OBJS   += $$($(1)_OBJS)
 endef

 $(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(eval $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))
```

I think this `foreach` should effectively expand to the following, before variable expansion:

```
server: $(server_OBJS) $(server_LIBS:%=-l%)
ALL_OBJS   += $(server_OBJS)

client: $(client_OBJS) $(client_LIBS:%=-l%)
ALL_OBJS   += $(client_OBJS)
```

I figured out the above expansion by hand (corrections welcome), but I'm looking for a general method to display this expansion for more complex examples.  Does such a method exist?

I have looked into `make -d` and `make -pn` options, and as far as I can tell, I don't think either of these will provide this particular output.

I'm using make-3.81.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace all your `$(eval ...)` calls with `$(info ...)`.  Actually if you're stuck with 3.81 you may have to use `$(warning ...)` and ignore the extra output, because I think `$(info ...)` might not have existed until version 3.82.

Anyway, writing:

```
$(foreach prog,$(PROGRAMS),$(info $(call PROGRAM_template,$(prog))))
```

(or warning) you'll see what make is parsing.

Comment: Excellent - that does exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Comment: By the way `$(info ...)` worked just fine for me with `make-3.81`.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a macro to help with seeing the results of $(eval ...):

```
# This version prints out rules for debugging
#c = $(eval $(call $(strip $1),$(strip $2),$(strip $3),$(strip $4),$(strip $5),$(strip $6),$(strip $7),$(strip $8),$(strip $9))) $(info $(call $(strip $1),$(strip $2),$(strip $3),$(strip $4),$(strip $5),$(strip $6),$(strip $7),$(strip $8),$(strip $9)))

# This version is the production version
c = $(eval $(call $(strip $1),$(strip $2),$(strip $3),$(strip $4),$(strip $5),$(strip $6),$(strip $7),$(strip $8),$(strip $9)))
```

Use it like this:

```
$(call c,function,arg1,arg2,...)
```

To see what is being generated by eval, simply use the debugging version.  I needed this instead of simply replacing $(eval  ...) by $(info ...) because functionality later in the makefile depended on the results of the $(eval ...)